# How to show element created in javascript as child?

Tags: javascript, html, console

I can successfully add div to my ".list-group" div and localstorage, they work dynamically. But these elements do not appear to be offspring of its container. If you try it in your own browser, you will see that it returns a null value. Why don't my list items appear as kids? And how can I make it appear Child. Thank's adavance for your answers. Codepen: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/xxEmQLo

```css
const form = document.querySelector("#todo-form");
const todoInput = document.querySelector("#todo");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const firstCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const secondCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];
const filter = document.querySelector("#filter");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear-todos");
let alert = document.getElementById("alertID");
eventListeners();
console.log(todoList.firstElementChild);

//Event Listeners

function eventListeners() {
    secondCardBody.addEventListener("click", deleteTodo);
    form.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadAllTodosToUI);
    filter.addEventListener("keyup", filterTodos);
    clearButton.addEventListener("click",clearAllTodos);
}

// Todo Ekleme

function addTodo(e) {
    const newTodo = todoInput.value.trim();
    if (newTodo === "") {
        showAlert("danger", "Lütfen bir todo giriniz");
    } else {
        showAlert("success", "Giriş Başarılı");
        addTodoToUI(newTodo);
        addTodoToStorage(newTodo);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}


function addTodoToUI(newTodo) {
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "#";
    link.className = "delete-item";
    link.innerHTML = " <i class = 'fa fa-remove'></i>";
    listItem.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTodo));
    listItem.appendChild(link);
    todoList.appendChild(listItem);
    todoInput.value = "";
}

// Alert

function showAlert(type, message) {
    let = alert;
    if (alert == null) {
        alert = document.createElement("div");
        alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
        alert.id = "alertID";
        alert.textContent = message;
        firstCardBody.appendChild(alert);
        alert.style.marginTop = "1rem";
    } else {
        alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
        alert.textContent = message;
        document.getElementById("alertID").style.display = 'block';
    }
    setTimeout (function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("alertID").style.display = 'none'; 
    }, 1000)
};

// Todo Storage Ekleme

function addTodoToStorage(newTodo) {
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

    todos.push(newTodo);

    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function getTodosFromStorage() { // Storage'den Todoları Almak
    let todos;
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
        todos = [];
    } else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    }
    return todos;
}

// Sayfa Yüklendiğinde Storage Yükleme

function loadAllTodosToUI() {
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        addTodoToUI(todo);
    })
}

// Todo Silme

function deleteTodo(e) {
    if (e.target.className === "fa fa-remove") {
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
}

// Todo Filtreleme

function filterTodos(e) {
    const filterValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item");

    listItems.forEach(function (listItem) {
        const text = listItem.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (text.indexOf(filterValue) === -1) {
            // Bulamadı
            listItem.setAttribute("style", "display : none !important");
        } else {
            listItem.setAttribute("style", "display : block");
        }
    });
}

// Tüm Todoları Silme

function clearAllTodos(e) {
    if (confirm("Tümünü Silmek istediğinize Emin Misiniz?")) {
        // Arayüzden Todoları Temizleme 
        // todoList.innerHTML = ""; // Yavaş Yöntem
    }
}
console.log(todoList.firstElementChild);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="berkay.css">
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="bal" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header">Todo List</div>
      <div class="card-body bdy">
        <form id="todo-form" name="form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="Bir Todo Girin"
                autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Todo Ekleyin</button>
        </form>
        <!-- <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          This is a danger alert—check it out!
        </div> -->
      </div>

      <div class="card-body body">
        <hr />
        <h5 class="card-title" id="tasks-title">Todolar</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="filter" id="filter" placeholder="Bir Todo Arayın"
              tabindex="2" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <ul class="list-group"></ul>
        <hr />
        <a id="clear-todos" class="btn btn-dark" href="#">Tüm Taskları Temizleyin</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="box2" style="display: none;"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="berkay.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dont know what is your problem, but when i add some todo on your codepen, and then when i go to browser console and check todoList variable, and todoList.firstElementChild it gives me li elements. I mean sure it gives you null, when you just open it, because there is nothing to show, and when you add some todos it shows them properly. And they even appear in todo list on the page.

Comment: @Xth Use you same codepen.io code? I add Todo in the body but still its dont work. Would You give to me your console screenshot? I still didn't.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1Z9IoeU

Comment: i mean you put console.log in wrong place, when variable is empty obviously. Try to put it at least in some function, like in last line of addTodoToUI or something, if you want see it via console.log exactly

Comment: It's so interesting. I watch a video and This encoder can do it but my console.log just show at addTodoToUI Function.